# Como plotar dados de uma variavel em shiny UI

Tags: shiny

Estou iniciando o aprendizado em R/Shiny.
Estou com dificuldade em plotar um gráfico na UI.

O conteúdo do gráfico vem da função "stock(tiker,rx),variavel "preco", segue a função:

```
stock<- function(ticker,rx){

re<- ({as.numeric(rx)})
#re=0
#ticker="vale3"
p1=ticker
p=140
#re=0#retrocede candles de 15 minutos
options(max.print=15)##qtdadde reg para impressao na tela

p1<-toupper(p1)
ta=length(p1)

options(max.print=15)##qtdadde reg para impressao na tela
p2="https://finance.google.com/finance/getprices?q="
p4="&x=BVMF&i=900&p=100d&f=c"
####################looping

URL<-paste(p2,p1,p4,sep="")
xx<- read.csv(URL)
colnames(xx)[1] <- "co1"  #muda none EXCHANGE.#DBMF para close
c1=(xx$co1)
t1=length(c1)
c2=c1[(t1-500):t1]
c3 <- c2[ c2 != "TIMEZONE_OFFSET=-180" ]
preco<-as.numeric(as.character(c3))###that that a want to plot in UI

return(paste0("Ativo.: ", p1, br()

#####
UI
library(shiny)
#modelo bom pasta apteste9
ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
  h3("Pesquisa Ativo da Bolsa -Defasados 15 Minutos,Fornece 5 periodos (top/down atual e 4 anteriores de 15 Minutos - Testes:"),

   h4("Sugestao Base, (W INDICATOR BUY & SELL),......... VENDA Qdo Wibs e WIbs1 >=9,..........  Compra Qdo WIBS E WIBS1  <=1:"),

  h5("Analise abrangendo 5 Dias de Pregao 15 em 15 Minutos,ou seja - Dados reais Defasados 15 Minutos -        Analise Base Modelagem Regressao x Ruido" ),

  br(),

  fluidRow(
    column(6,selectizeInput("ticker", "Selecione Ativo Desejado,ou Digite Nome da Empresa", width="100%",multiple=TRUE,
                            choices = list("AMBEV S/A"="ABEV3","BRASIL"="BBAS3","BRADESCO"="BBDC3","BRADESCO"="BBDC4",

                                           "BBSEGURIDADE"="BBSE3","BRADESPAR"="BRAP4","BRF SA"="BRFS3"))),

    column(3,selectizeInput("rx", "Retroceder x Candles de 15 Minutos", width="100%",
                            choices = list(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,22))),
    br(),
    br(),
    column(3,actionButton(inputId = "input_action", label = "Processa os Dados.???"))   
  ),  
  mainPanel(
    h5(textOutput("caption")),    
    tableOutput("saida")),
    plotOutput("plot")



###server

library(shiny)
source("stock.R",local = TRUE)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {   


  observeEvent(input$input_action, {
    ticker= input$ticker
    rx = input$rx
    output$saida <- renderTable({
    stock(ticker,rx)
    })    
  })
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    source("stock.R",local = TRUE)   
    plot<-preco
  }) 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

O código que você disponibilizou estava todo problemático.

A começar pela falta de (), {}, ... fechando corretamente os enviroments, funções, etc. Seje mais cuidadoso pra facilitar a vida de quem vai analisar a sua dúvida.

Outro problema, se você deseja que a função `stock` retorne o vetor de preços então ele é quem deve estar dentro de `return()`. Uma função do R segue duas linhas de pensamento, ou ela retorna o objeto na última linha ou ela retorna o objeto que estiver dentro do primeiro `return()` que for chamado (e acaba aí).

Agora na parte do Shiny propriamente dito. Você não deve colocar `output$saida <- renderTable({...})` dentro de um `observeEvent({})`, toda função *render...* deve ser primária dentro do `server`.

Outro ponto, se você chamar a função `stock(ticker,rx)` dentro `renderTable({...})` ele não estará diponível dentro do `renderPlot({...})` pois são dois ambientes diferentes.

Como você vai usar os dados para dois outputs diferentes (tabela e gráfico) sugiro que você crie eles como um ambiente reactive (que é uma função que reage às mudanças nos inputs) e chame dentro de cada um desses renders.

Ai vai seu código modificado e funcionando.

```
library(shiny)

stock<- function(ticker,rx){

  re<- ({as.numeric(rx)})
  #re=0
  #ticker="vale3"
  p1=ticker
  p=140
  #re=0#retrocede candles de 15 minutos
  options(max.print=15)##qtdadde reg para impressao na tela

  p1<-toupper(p1)
  ta=length(p1)

  options(max.print=15)##qtdadde reg para impressao na tela
  p2="https://finance.google.com/finance/getprices?q="
  p4="&x=BVMF&i=900&p=100d&f=c"
  ####################looping

  URL<-paste(p2,p1,p4,sep="")
  xx<- read.csv(URL)
  colnames(xx)[1] <- "co1"  #muda none EXCHANGE.#DBMF para close
  c1=(xx$co1)
  t1=length(c1)
  c2=c1[(t1-500):t1]
  c3 <- c2[ c2 != "TIMEZONE_OFFSET=-180" ]

  preco<-as.numeric(as.character(c3))###that that a want to plot in UI
  return(preco)
}

#####


ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    h3("Pesquisa Ativo da Bolsa -Defasados 15 Minutos,Fornece 5 periodos (top/down atual e 4 anteriores de 15 Minutos - Testes:"),
    h4("Sugestao Base, (W INDICATOR BUY & SELL),......... VENDA Qdo Wibs e WIbs1 >=9,..........  Compra Qdo WIBS E WIBS1  <=1:"),
    h5("Analise abrangendo 5 Dias de Pregao 15 em 15 Minutos,ou seja - Dados reais Defasados 15 Minutos -        Analise Base Modelagem Regressao x Ruido" ),
    br(),

    fluidRow(
      column(6,selectizeInput("ticker", "Selecione Ativo Desejado,ou Digite Nome da Empresa", width="100%",multiple=TRUE,
                              choices = list("AMBEV S/A"="ABEV3","BRASIL"="BBAS3","BRADESCO"="BBDC3","BRADESCO"="BBDC4",
                                             "BBSEGURIDADE"="BBSE3","BRADESPAR"="BRAP4","BRF SA"="BRFS3"))),
      column(3,selectizeInput("rx", "Retroceder x Candles de 15 Minutos", width="100%",
                              choices = list(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,22),
                              selected= character(0))),
      br(),
      br(),
      column(3,actionButton(inputId = "input_action", label = "Processa os Dados.???"))   
    ),  
    mainPanel(
      h5(textOutput("caption")),    
      tableOutput("saida")),
    plotOutput("plot")
  )
)


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {   

  data <- reactive({
    # atualizado apenas quando clicar no botão
    req(input$input_action)
    # Conferindo se o ticker foi escolhido
    req(input$ticker)
    # retornando os inputs
    ticker <- input$ticker
    rx <- input$rx
    # retorna o vetor de preços
    stock(ticker,rx)
  })

  output$saida <- renderTable({
    data()
  }) 

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(data())
  }) 
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```